# Tweaking pgfplots for beauty: margins, boundaries, alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created the following graph, but I don't find it very beautiful. I have some ideas of what would make it look better (below) which I do not know how to implement. Can someone show me how to make these modifications, or ignore my thoughts but provide an alternate example making the graph more visually appealing?

- Left-align instead of centre the words in the legend
- Graph is square rather than rectangular, and does not include half-squares (includes correct codes 0-2)
- Lines are thicker/more pronounced
- Graph does not extend left and right beyond the range of X values used (starts at 1, ends at 10)
- Y axis label is not so far to the left of the graph

.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,review, anonymous]{acmart}
\citestyle{acmauthoryear}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,multirow,array,titlecaps}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,subcaption}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[stack plots=false,
  ylabel={Correct Codes},
  xlabel={Keyword Frequency (Code)},
  cycle list name=color list,
  grid=major,
  legend style={at={(0,-.2)}, anchor=north west},
]

\addplot
   coordinates {(1,5)(2,5)(3,4)(4,5)(5,5)(6,5)(7,5)(8,5)(9,5)(10,5)};
\addplot
   coordinates {(1,9)(2,6)(3,6)(4,5)(5,4)(6,5)(7,6)(8,5)(9,5)(10,5)};
%% Color difference was not sufficient in default, forcing new colour
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=+2}
\addplot
   coordinates {(1,6)(2,7)(3,7)(4,6)(5,7)(6,9)(7,10)(8,10)(9,9)(10,9)};
%% Color difference was not sufficient in default, forcing new colour
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=+2}
\addplot
   coordinates {(1,7)(2,6)(3,5)(4,5)(5,7)(6,4)(7,4)(8,4)(9,4)(10,5)};

\legend{WordCount,KeywordRelevance,KeywordCount,DISCOKeywords}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{subfigure}
\caption{Keyword Frequency (Code)}
\label{fig:keyword-frequency}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Concerning the thickness of the lines, you can use `\addplot+[thick]` instead of `\addplot`. And even replace `thick`  by `very thick` if necessary.

Comment: For the position of the Y axis label, you can use `ylabel near ticks` in your `axis` environment parameters.

Comment: `xmin=1,xmax=10` should reduce the x axis as you want.

Comment: `legend cell align=left` for the legend alignment.

Answer (score 5):

There sometimes are several ways of doing things, and the pointers from mvienney are helpful.

Are you aware of the [PGFplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), which is even more helpful, and filled with examples ? Every thing you asked is covered in that document.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
    %stack plots=false, % not useful here.
    unit vector ratio=1 1, % same size for both unit axis vectors
    title={My title: Keyword Frequency (Code)}, % 
    title style=
    {
      at = {(0,0)},
      anchor = north west,
      yshift=-1.5cm,
      font=\LARGE,
    },
    ylabel={Correct Codes},
    ylabel style=
    {
      yshift=-4mm, 
      %you can set other attributes here if you like
      %red % e.g.
    },
    xlabel={Keyword Frequency (Code)},
    cycle list name=color list,
    grid=major,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style=
    {
      cells={anchor=west},
      outer ysep=0pt,
    },
    %legend style=
    %{
    %  at={(0,-.2)}, anchor=north west
    %},
    %
    % this sets the window of values to be displayed 
    xmin=0,
    xmax=11.5,
    ymin=0,
    every axis plot post/.style={very thick},
  ]

  \addplot coordinates {(1,5)(2,5)(3,4)(4,5)(5,5)(6,5)(7,5)(8,5)(9,5)(10,5)};
  \addplot coordinates {(1,9)(2,6)(3,6)(4,5)(5,4)(6,5)(7,6)(8,5)(9,5)(10,5)};
  %% Color difference was not sufficient in default, forcing new colour
  \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=+2}
  \addplot coordinates {(1,6)(2,7)(3,7)(4,6)(5,7)(6,9)(7,10)(8,10)(9,9)(10,9)};
  %% Color difference was not sufficient in default, forcing new colour
  \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=+2}
  \addplot coordinates {(1,7)(2,6)(3,5)(4,5)(5,7)(6,4)(7,4)(8,4)(9,4)(10,5)};

  \legend{WordCount,KeywordRelevance,KeywordCount,DISCOKeywords}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did consult the guide, which I used to learn how to create the basic graph. Then I only searched for the changes I was trying to make. In some cases, such as the line colours and adding the grid, I managed to hit upon the right keywords, but for the other issues I did not. Thank you for showing me most of the things that I was looking for (thicker lines, grid spacing, legend alignment, Y-axis label).

Comment: It's true that certain keys are plain TikZ and documented in the [PGF/Tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: I see that I can adjust the xmin and xmax values to set the lines against the edge of the graph, and now I also have a better idea of how to place the legend (sadly, due to 2-column constraints, it has to be above or below). I appreciate that you gave me part of the answer and let me figure out the rest.